# make direction of excel sheets of my birt report right to left

Tags: excel, report, birt, right-to-left, birt-emitter

I have a birt report with excel output. I want to make the sheet direction right to left.
I try to do this via adding new style, but the style just make the text in cells right to left, not the direction of excel sheets itself.

Comment: I've already made the general report orientation Right to Left

Answer (score 0):

This is an unresolved issue in BIRT. The report orientation does not work for XLS/XLSX. It might be either because of the way BIRT transmits BIRT-elements into excel cells or simply because no XLS-transmitter supports the feature. However, it does at least work for PDF - if that helps.

Eventually, you might just want to recreate that report with the desired orientation. To "align" elements like a headline most-right, you usually create a grid with a number of colums that equals or exceeds the number of columns of the data table. Then you put the headline element in the right-most cell of that grid.

Hope you find a way!

Comment: @raziehhafizi, if you are able to solve it in any way, comment it here, so that other people can also find solution. =)

Comment: sure I will inform you if I find a way :)